# css unordered list menu resembles 'steps' in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, menu

my menu is working fine on the good browsers. The code is all valid (so far!). In IE though it looks like a staircase, each menu item is a few pixels down from it left neighbour. It should all be horizontal.

[Please have a look here](http://www.digiflipconcepts.com/daycare/templates/daycare/)

[alt text http://www.digiflipconcepts.com/images/bbdc-menu-anomaly.jpg](http://www.digiflipconcepts.com/images/bbdc-menu-anomaly.jpg)

Comment: Works fine in IE8, by the way.  I'm sure you're referring to both IE6 and 7.  (I cannot test myself at this time.)

Comment: Yes sorry I should have mentioned - IE6 and 7 are where the issue occurs

Comment: The link doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply `display: inline` to `ul.menu li`.

Comment: Thanks Strager, you are a legend! That has fixed it :).

Answer (score 0):

my first guess would be either padding or margin on your li elements. see if this helps:

```
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

(spoke too soon, looks like you do have that in there)

on third glance, it looks like you're setting the following:

```
ul.menu li a {
  display: block
  padding: 11px 0 0;
}
```

see if removing that 11px padding helps

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it without the padding but it is still the same :(